# Python automation tests: ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to get one of my Python automation tests working but unfortunately I encounter this error: ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The machine specs are: Linux crazlulinuxuser 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have installed the correct packages and here is the output from the absolute path for lapack:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack$ ls -Faithsl
total 19M
1060118 120K drwxr-xr-x 148 root root 116K Apr 25 14:07 ../
1705054 4.0K drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Apr 25 14:05 ./
1714629  12M -rw-r--r--   1 root root  12M Sep 13  2017 liblapack.a
1725288    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 13  2017 liblapack.so -> liblapack.so.3.7.1
1706104    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 13  2017 liblapack.so.3 -> liblapack.so.3.7.1
```

I have the following entry in .bashrc file: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nest-python/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack

I did follow other StackOverflow solutions to similar problems but wasn't successful in getting it working.

What am I missing. Could someone help me troubleshoot on this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Well if you are using something like Jenkins there are login shells and non-login shells which don't process .rc files.  So I would be interested in seeing the actual value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH live from the actual bash prompt you are using.  Also I find the "gf" in .3gf suspicious . . . why is the gf there?

Comment: @Frank On a bash shell doing a echo for LD_LIBRARY_PATH command gives: echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/mypython/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/

I am sorry I am not sure about the 3gf appended at the end. I googled and could find posts with exact names ending in 3gf

Comment: So "lapack" is missing . . . you might add a second entry with lapack and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @FrankMerrow it worked with this workaround for a while but now I face a similar error -- ImportError: libblas.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I did create a symbolic link: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3gf

I updated the ~/.bashrc with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/local/nest-python/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/atlas:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas
But the issue persists. Any pointers? Plz let me know.